# Getting random string from JSON File

Tags: java, json

Trying to get a random word from this JSON file

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject obj = JSONUtils.getJSONObjectFromFile("/adjs.json");

        JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("adjs");

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i));
        }

        Random r = new Random();
        int id1 = r.nextInt(jsonArray.length());
        String word1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(id1).getString("adjs");
        System.out.println(word1);
        //String word = jsonArray.getJSONObject(r.nextInt(jsonArray.length())).getString("adjs");
    }
}
```

There is the code I am using and I keep getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[671] is not a JSONObject.
    at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:428)
    at Job.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

How can I achieve it?

Below is the JSON I'm working with:

```
{
    "description": "A list of English adjectives.",
    "adjs":
    [ 
        "Aristotelian",
        "Arthurian",
        "Bohemian",
        "Brethren",
        "Mosaic",
        "Oceanic",
        "Proctor",
        "Terran",
        "Tudor",
        "abroad",
        "absorbing",
        "abstract",
        "academic",
        "accelerated",
        "accented",
        "accountant",
        "acquainted",
        "acute",
        "addicting",
        "addictive",
        "adjustable",
        "admired",
        "adult",
        "adverse",
        "advised"
    ]
}
```

Looking for ways around it. Oh yea is just a little bit of the JSON file.

Comment: Please share (relevant parts of ) the JSON you're working with. `is not a JSONObject` is a hint that points to the data having a problem, not necessarily the code.

Comment: Try printing the contents of `/adjs.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String word1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(id1).getString("adjs");
```

The variable `jsonArray` contains a `JSONArray`, which contains *strings*, not nested `JSONObject`s.  What you want is

```
String word1 = jsonArray.getString(id1);
```

The code you actually wrote expects JSON in the following form:

```
{
    "description": "A list of English adjectives.",
    "adjs":
    [
        { "adjs": "Aristotelian" },
        { "adjs": "Arthurian" },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Mentioning the key `"adjs"` twice in your code could have been a clue :-)

Comment: My bad the //String word = jsonArray.getJSONObject(r.nextInt(jsonArray.length())).getString("adjs"); was another attemt